# What does (within one month of the last day of the period of the suspension) mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> A scholarship shall be terminated **if a scholarship recipient ceases to resume the aforesaid programme of research *within one month of the last day of the period of the suspension***.

Could you say what this sentence says?

Comment: It looks like a mistake to me--it should probably be "**fails** to resume". If so, then it seems to address a situation where a scholarship recipient is working on a research project which has been formally suspended for a (fixed?) period; when that suspension ends, the scholarship recipient must start working on it again within one month or lose their scholarship. But I can't be sure without more context.

Comment: @StoneyB It is page 3 no. 15 in this link: http://www.victoria.ac.nz/scholarship/forms/vicdoc-regs.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context provided by the preceding paragraph shows that the word  *ceases*  is an error.

> Once the period of tenure of a scholarship has commenced, the Scholarships Manager may, grant a scholarship recipient a suspension of their scholarship for a period not exceeding six months or a total of twelve months during the first three years of registration. As the monthly stipend is paid in advance the recipient must provide notification in advance of the suspension. In most cases the scholarship suspension will coincide with a formal suspension from their Doctoral enrolment. Scholarship recipients must ensure that any commitments related to their work experience are discussed with the Head of School before the suspension is agreed.

The sentence you quote should read “A scholarship shall be terminated if a scholarship recipient **fails** to resume the aforesaid programme of research...”

That is, a scholarship recipient may be granted a *suspension*—a period during which he or she is not required to perform activity on the research progamme. The *suspension* is for a fixed period, with a definite ending date—that ending date is the point at which ***the suspension is terminated.***

The recipient must ***resume the ... programme of research*** (= start working on the programme again) ***within one month*** (=during the month and no later) ***after*** that date. If the recipient ***fails to*** (=does not) resume work, then the scholarship ***shall be terminated*** (=will come to an end).

I would guess that this error, *ceases* for *fails*, came about because the document has been revised from time to time, and the person or committee revising this passage started with a sentence (perhaps cut-and-pasted from another document) which had something like  *if [so-and-so] ceases to perform the duties...*  That's how documents like this get written, and there are other awkward sentences and some very odd punctuation in it which suggest this.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence means:

> A scholarship shall be terminated if a scholarship recipient **does not** resume the aforesaid programme of research within one month, **after the suspension is terminated.**